# PHP how to invert a scale of numbers

Tags: php

Say I have a dataset, each element has an associated "score".

eg:
Banana - 5
Apple - 3
Pear - 2

I want to invert the scale so that :
All 5's become 1's
All 4's become 2's
All 3's become 3's
All 2's become 4's
All 1's become 5's

So I'd end up with
Banana - 1
Apple - 3
Pear - 4

I'm struggling to find a graceful solution that doesn't involve creating a map.

Comment: What's wrong on `echo (6-$i)`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is `$new = -$old + 6`. Just use it with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$initial = array(
  'Banana' => 5,
  'Apple' => 3,
  'Pear' => 2,
);

$max = max($initial);
foreach ($initial as &$val) {
  $val = $max + 1 - $val;
}

print_r($initial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all elements, and calculate the new "score" like this:

```
$score_new = ($score_old - 6) * (-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula for other scale ranges:

```
$new = $rangeMax + $rangeMin - $old
```